# Fix This std::async Call

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++14

Having trouble with `std::async`, every way I write it turns out to be illegal. Anyone got any suggestions?

PS: It's an async IP range scanner.

```
bool PortCheck(std::string ip, int port)
{

}

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::future<bool>>> JobPool;

std::future<bool > f = PortCheck(argStartAddress, argPort);


JobPool.push_back(std::make_pair(
    argStartAddress,
    f
));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: StackOverflow has those requirements for a reason. There's a lot of code here that is irrelevant to your question; it makes it much more difficult to answer. Please make a minimum, complete, and verifiable example (the smallest thing you can that reproduces the problem).

Comment: `std::future<bool> f = std::async(std::launch::async, PortCheck, argStartAddress, argPort);`

Answer (score 0):

```
std::future<bool> f = std::async(PortCheck, argStartAddress, argPort);

JobPool.push_back(std::make_pair(
    argStartAddress,
    std::move(f)  // note std::move
));
```

Comment: Doesnt work, "std::future<bool > f = std::async(PortCheck, argStartAddress, argPort);" is illegal

Comment: https://imghost.io/images/2017/01/08/699f149900a0020f607a5a120d6ed498.png

Comment: In your real code, is `PortCheck` a member function of some class, by any chance? I can't help but notice that you neglected to mention this significant fact. Hence the importance of providing [an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So then, show a class it's a member of, and an instance of that class on which you wish to call `PortCheck`. In other words, prepare an MCVE.